# Issues withs KatRisk software and R studio software

Tags: r, dt

The user tried to install the `DT` package as per the katrisk instruction in R-studio software. But it completely wiped out of her shiny package(which we run katrisk). So she tried to reinstall it again but it failed with an error:

> Error Message: unexpected input in "install package"

Comment: There's absolutely no reason why running `install.packages("DT")` would wipe out anything.

Comment: The function is `install.packages`, not `install package` (that is, replace the space with a dot, and add an `s`). The only time I've seen an installation attempt of one package cause another to fail is when it is "in use" during installation: the old package directory is wiped/moved but because of DLL handles still open, the new directory cannot be put into place. (`shiny` should not do this since it has no compiled code, but perhaps something else broke it.) Regardless: restart R, then `install.packages(c("shiny","DT"))` and it should be fine.

Comment: We can try to restart R, then install.packages(c("shiny","DT")) this way open Katrisk;  in R we have to type 2 commands.  library(shiny)   then RunApp()....after runApp; katisk opens.....I typed in library(shiny);  it  ran a bunch of commands and finally stopped with --- Error in library(shiny) : there is no package called ‘shiny’. can you advise resolve this issue